# How Can I Create a Regular Expression to Match a String Like This?

Tags: regex, cloud9-ide

I am using Cloud9's IDE and want to use their regex search/replace feature to find all lines of code that look like this:

`LINE -(xxx, yyy)`

Example:

`LINE -(135, 400)`

I came up with

`/LINE -\(\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}\)\n/g`

This works in [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3cddr) but not in [Cloud9](http://www.c9.io/). I've tried a few variations without any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: `LINE -\(\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}\)` this works , I guess the IDE `cloud9` doesn't support regular expression delimiters

Answer (score 2):

A few notes about Cloud9 find panel using a Regex:

- You don't need to add the `/` delimiters
- The trailing `/g` is also not needed
- You need to enable regex mode in the find box by clicking on the button that says: `.*?`

I tried the above regex with a dummy file and it worked. Here's the final find query I gave:

```
LINE -\(\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}\)
```